# HttpWebRequest getting different response from SharePoint server than everything else

Tags: c#, xml, iis, sharepoint, rss

I'm trying to connect to a Sharepoint server and fetch an RSS feed in C#. It seems a simple enough task, however for some reason when I send an HttpWebRequest, sharepoint sends me a different response to what I get for visiting the feed in a browser. Specificially, it returns the feed without any s.

The code for making the request is the following:

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(URL) as HttpWebRequest;
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials; //NTLM

using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse) {
    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    // debug: dump the response.
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine((new StreamReader(responseStream)).ReadToEnd());
...
```

In testing this code, I tried it on a public RSS feed and it works fine. I booted up wireshark to have a look to see if there was something different about the request sent by C#, the requests and responses looked like this:

```
GET /Test_Blog_B/_layouts/15/listfeed.aspx?List=%7B5600FFF4-50CD-47C5-BEBC-602874E73748%7D HTTP/1.1
    HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized  (text/plain)
GET /Test_Blog_B/_layouts/15/listfeed.aspx?List=%7B5600FFF4-50CD-47C5-BEBC-602874E73748%7D HTTP/1.1 
    HTTP/XML    438 HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!--RSS generated by Microsoft SharePoint Foundation RSS Generator on 12/18/2014 3:50:28 PM -->
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/Test_Blog_B/_layouts/15/RssXslt.aspx?List=5600fff4-50cd-47c5-bebc-602874e73748" version="1.0"?>
    <rss version="2.0">
      <channel>
        <title>Blog: Posts</title>
        <link>http://servername/Test_Blog_B/Lists/Posts/AllPosts.aspx</link>
        <description>RSS feed for the Posts list.</description>
        <lastBuildDate>Thu, 18 Dec 2014 15:50:28 GMT</lastBuildDate>
        <generator>Microsoft SharePoint Foundation RSS Generator</generator>
        <ttl>60</ttl>
        <language>en-US</language>
        <image>
          <title>Blog: Posts</title>
          <url>http://servername/Test_Blog_B/_layouts/15/images/siteIcon.png</url>
          <link>http://servername/Test_Blog_B/Lists/Posts/AllPosts.aspx</link>
        </image>
      </channel>
    </rss>
```

However, everything else I try gets this response (cURL output, snipped out some of the headers for brevity)

```
* Connected to servername (192.168.170.39) port 80 (#0)
* Server auth using NTLM with user 
> GET /Test_Blog_B/_layouts/15/listfeed.aspx?List=%7B5600FFF4-50CD-47C5-BEBC-602
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
* Connection #0 to host servername left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'http://servername/Test_Blog_B/_layouts/15/list
feed.aspx?List=%7B5600FFF4-50CD-47C5-BEBC-602874E73748%7D'
* Found bundle for host servername: 0x94eab0
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host servername
* Connected to servername (192.168.170.39) port 80 (#0)
* Server auth using NTLM with user ''
> GET /Test_Blog_B/_layouts/15/listfeed.aspx?List=%7B5600FFF4-50CD-47C5-BEBC-602
874E73748%7D HTTP/1.1
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: private
< Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
< Last-Modified: Thu, 18 Dec 2014 15:13:06 GMT
< ETag: 1;3;5600fff4-50cd-47c5-bebc-602874e73748;635545156307000000;13319
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
< X-SharePointHealthScore: 0
< X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
< SPRequestGuid: 7b06d79c-dd72-c064-3da9-961822afeee3
< request-id: 7b06d79c-dd72-c064-3da9-961822afeee3
< X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
< SPRequestDuration: 65
< SPIisLatency: 1
< Persistent-Auth: true
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 15.0.0.4569
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
< Date: Thu, 18 Dec 2014 16:28:44 GMT
< Content-Length: 3061
<
´╗┐<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--RSS generated by Microsoft SharePoint Foundation RSS Generator on 12/18/2014
 4:28:44 PM -->
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/Test_Blog_B/_layouts/15/RssXslt.aspx?Lis
t=5600fff4-50cd-47c5-bebc-602874e73748" version="1.0"?>
<rss version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>Blog: Posts</title>
    <link>http://servername/Test_Blog_B/Lists/Posts/AllPosts.aspx</link>
    <description>RSS feed for the Posts list.</description>
    <lastBuildDate>Thu, 18 Dec 2014 16:28:44 GMT</lastBuildDate>
    <generator>Microsoft SharePoint Foundation RSS Generator</generator>
    <ttl>60</ttl>
    <language>en-US</language>
    <image>
      <title>Blog: Posts</title>
      <url>http://servername/Test_Blog_B/_layouts/15/images/siteIcon.png</url>
      <link>http://servername/Test_Blog_B/Lists/Posts/AllPosts.aspx</link>
    </image>
    <item>
      <title>Blog</title>
      <link>http://servername/Test_Blog_B/Lists/Posts/ViewPost.aspx?ID=3</link>
      <description><![CDATA[<div><b>Body:</b> <div class="ExternalClass78B241D68
AE340AF8482D70142AE8DB7"><p>Post</p></div></div>
<div><b>Published:</b> 12/18/2014 3:12 PM</div>
]]></description>
      <author></author>
      <pubDate>Thu, 18 Dec 2014 15:13:06 GMT</pubDate>
      <guid isPermaLink="true">http://servername/Test_Blog_B/Lists/Posts/ViewPost.as
px?ID=3</guid>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>new post</title>
      <link>http://servername/Test_Blog_B/Lists/Posts/ViewPost.aspx?ID=2</link>
      <description><![CDATA[<div><b>Body:</b> <div class="ExternalClass0BD87B46B
E6F481CA042F2BACC15082C"><p>2ÔÇï</p></div></div>
<div><b>Category:</b> <a onclick="OpenPopUpPage('http://servername/Test_Blog_B/_layo
uts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=4&ListId={7C658DFF-4CEC-4934-98C3-14187E2345CA}&ID
=3&RootFolder=*', RefreshPage); return false;" href="http://servername/Test_Blog_B/_
layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=4&ListId={7C658DFF-4CEC-4934-98C3-14187E2345CA
}&ID=3&RootFolder=*">Events</a></div>
<div><b>Published:</b> 12/11/2014 4:55 PM</div>
]]></description>
      <author></author>
      <category>Events</category>
      <pubDate>Thu, 11 Dec 2014 16:55:38 GMT</pubDate>
      <guid isPermaLink="true">http://servername/Test_Blog_B/Lists/Posts/ViewPost.as
px?ID=2</guid>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>Welcome to my blog!</title>
      <link>http://servername/Test_Blog_B/Lists/Posts/ViewPost.aspx?ID=1</link>
      <description><![CDATA[<div><b>Body:</b> <div class="ExternalClass471F21A09
57043359622B8C8ABB138CF"><p>This is where I'll be sharing my thoughts on topics
that matter to me. Who knows... I might even share pictures, videos and links to
 other interesting stuff.</p><p>If I catch your interest, let me hear from you.<
/p></div></div>
<div><b>Published:</b> 12/11/2014 3:04 PM</div>
]]></description>
      <author></author>
      <pubDate>Thu, 11 Dec 2014 15:04:03 GMT</pubDate>
      <guid isPermaLink="true">http://servername/Test_Blog_B/Lists/Posts/ViewPost.as
px?ID=1</guid>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>* Connection #0 to host servername left intact
```

This is a normal SharePoint blog on a clean install of Sharepoint 2013. Opening this feed in the browser gives the same result as CURL, so I can't see how my C# code is being served something different.

Any help with the causes of this is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution is that CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials takes the credentials of what's running the IIS server, which isn't my own credentials. Giving the code my own credentials works and gives the expected output.